# Why doesn't the image appear?

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code and put it in an html tester. An image is supposed to appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var heroRadius = 20;
var heroX = 50;
var heroY = 50;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var heroSpeed = 2;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 87) {
    upPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 83) {
    downPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 65){
    leftPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 68){
    rightPressed = true;
}
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 87) {
    upPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 83) {
    downPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 65) {
    leftPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode = 68) {
    rightPressed = false;
}
}

function drawHero() {
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 100);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
}

function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawHero();

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I want to make a game using an image and I made this as practice. The image appears if I remove requestAnimationFrame, but I will need that for when I add movement. Why doesn't the image appear?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
function drawHero() {
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 100);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
}
```

Don't do this at all.
Every frame would need to wait for the onload to finish.
Instead, first make an init function and attach it to your bodys onload event.
In this function, fill a class level Image variable with the src of your darth vader.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
function init(){
   imageObj.src='http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
}
```

Then in your draw loop it would be this.

```
function drawHero() {  
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 100);  
}
```

Canvas won't actually care that the image hasn't loaded yet so you don't really need to attach an onload event to it.

Also, although you aren't far enough yet, don't draw to the display canvas.  Draw to a hidden canvas, then draw the completed hidden canvas to the display canvas.  This will give much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your image does not appear because you did not call the load method of your Image object. You only specified what it has to do when a particular event is happening (here, loading).

Here is the working piece of code :

```
function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawHero();
imageObj.load()

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

However, I suggest you follow the advice given by the other contributors in terms of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `requestAnimationFrame(draw);` within your `draw` function which is calling your `draw` function about 60 times per second. In your `draw` function you also have `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` which is clearing your canvas. Therefore your image will not show up. I have only dabbled with using canvas so I am by no means an expert but that's the issue in your code.

[Read more about requestAnimationFrame here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

[Read more about clearRect here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p91ovude/1/). All I did was comment out requestAnimationFrame(draw) in your `draw` function.

You should do something like what [Trevor D is doing in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44767203/4760460). Since you most likely want that background image to stay unaffected.